# Changing the type of relationship between tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables that have a one-to-many relationship. The primary key of table 1 is a foreign key in table 2, but not it's primary key. The primary key is auto generated.The relationship should and IS a one-to-one relationship and not a one-to-many relationship.

This is what I want to alter, but I believe it has auto defaulted to a one-to-many relationship simply because the foreign key is not the primary key for this table

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a one-to-one relationship between two tables, it means that for one record in T1 there is at most one corresponding record in T2, and vice versa.

In your case if you want to ensure that for one record in t2 (semantic record, i.e ignoring the primary key of t2) there is at most one corresponding record in t1, you should add a UNIQUE constraint on all the semantic columns in t2 (i.e. columns semantically describing a record of t2, excluding the primary and the foreign key). This way you will make sure that a record in t2 will not point to two or more records in t1.

If you want to ensure the other direction of the one-to-one relationship (i.e. that a record in t1 is referenced by at most one record in t2) you should make the foreign key in t2 UNIQUE.

Comment: yea I was assuming it was because I did not have the t2 key Unique for the foreign column